# I'm using Railo 3.1 and CFSearch, I want to distribute across several machines

Tags: lucene, railo, verity

Can I rsync lucene indexes (every 5mins) to another pair of boxes and run the same app just for search?

I'm not interested in doing App Server Clustering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it doesn't seem to work.

cfsearch didn't work with copied files, maybe it requires something in memory.

Rebuilding indexes on each individual machine is good enough for us.